# Want to use Javascript instead of vw for my font size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't want to use vw in my font because it is not supported in many browsers and devices. So I want to use Javascript instead of vw so that my font size changes as I resize my screen. Can anyone provide me full code? Just give me a complete example with full code, then i'll do it myself :) Thank You.

Comment: google it for free codes :D

Comment: Viewport units are supported in over 93% of browsers/devices and should be considered safe to use. Which combinations are you having trouble with? https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Just wanted to know how to do the same with JS so that i don't get any problem in future - Jon Uleis

Comment: Post a minimal sample that summarizes what you tried, and explain which desired behavior you failed to achieve. It'll make it easier for both parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super simple example. You need to add a `resize` event listener to the window and then depending on the screen size (`innerWidth`) you can change the style of an element.

(Run example in Full Page mode)

**EDIT:** Added text resizing on each window resize. Change the `fontSize` to set the intial size.

```js
let fontSize = 38;
let lastWidth = 0;

window.addEventListener('resize', e => {

  if(window.innerWidth < lastWidth) {
    fontSize = fontSize - 2;
    document.querySelector('span').style.fontSize = `${fontSize}px`;
  } else {
    fontSize = fontSize + 2;
    document.querySelector('span').style.fontSize = `${fontSize}px`;
  }
  
  lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
});
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 38px;
}
```

```html
<span>Text Size</span>
```

Comment: This was helpful but i want the font size changed whenever i resize the window even a bit!  Same like when we give height and width to image in % and whenever we resize the window its size changes very smoothly. i want the same with font size but without vw - Chase DeAnda

Comment: Well, he posted a full example code, you said: " Just give me a complete example with full code, then i'll do it myself", it's your time now

Comment: Calvin Nunes i edited the comment now tell me

Comment: @XavierFoster Update example. Check it out now. You can tweak it from here to make it as "smooth" as you need.

Comment: Chase DeAnda Thnks a lot Sir :) It really helped me :D

Comment: Chase DeAnda can u again write that code which you wrote before editing this code! i want the old simple code, it was helpful too :)